# Why there is a field named "language" in the CakePHP's config file

Tags: cakephp

Well, I was going through an application where a find a variable named as "language" in the config file of the Cake application.Then I also found the same thing in the Bootstrap,where it called the same thing from config file.Could anyone explain me what does this thing do from the config file.Is there any rule Globalization behind this...???
please explain...!!!

Comment: Have you referred to cakephp's help docs? I would imagine this is a language based plugin/module for strings used in the app.
http://book.cakephp.org/view/163/Localization-in-CakePHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documents explain it pretty well:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/162/Internationalizing-Your-Application

You basically setup your language files, then the configuration setting in the core.php file decides which language you are going to display.

The neat thing about Cake Localization is that all you have to do is wrap all of your content in __('') which will automatically localize your content.